# Why is $f(x)=1/x$ uniformly continuous on $[a, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

It’s well known that $f(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$, but for any $a>0$, it is uniformly continuous on $[a, \infty)$.

Given an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, how do I choose the appropriate $\delta>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right|=\dfrac{|x-y|}{|x||y|}\leq\dfrac{1}{a^{2}}|x-y|$, the choice of $\delta>0$ should be clear.

Comment: I got to this step but I’m not sure how to choose $\delta$

Comment: Then simply choose $\delta=a^{2}\epsilon$.

Comment: Wow how did I miss that! Thanks!